# Using regex to remove everything after "..."

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like this:

> "Product DescriptionThe Signature Series treatment makes the strategy
>   guide a COLLECTIBLE ITEM for StarCraft II fans. Single-player CAMPAIGN
>   WALKTHROUGH covers all possible mission branches, including bonus
>   objectives throughout the campaign. Exclusive MAPS found only in the
>   official guide, show locations of units,... \n\n\n\n\n\n\nRead More\n"

How can I use regex the `.text[/(...)/]` to remove what's after the `...` so that it outputs like below?

> "Product DescriptionThe Signature Series treatment makes the strategy
>   guide a COLLECTIBLE ITEM for StarCraft II fans. Single-player CAMPAIGN
>   WALKTHROUGH covers all possible mission branches, including bonus
>   objectives throughout the campaign. Exclusive MAPS found only in the
>   official guide, show locations of units,..."

Comment: Why don't you split by `...` and take only the first element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the period.

```
string.sub(/(?<=\.\.\.).*/m, "")
```

or

```
string[/.*\.\.\./m]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the split method, something like that (I'm not that familiar with Ruby).

```
arr = text.split("...")  #=> text before '...' and text after '...'
arr[0]                   #=> text before '...'
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use lookarounds, you could simply do something like:

```
string.sub(/\.{3}.*/s, "...")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
/(^.*)(\.\­.\..*)/.ma­tch(string).captur­es[0]
```